# How can I order multiple ActiveRecords in rails by time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

In my controller, I needed to add logical operators like || and && in my but it's not working so I thought it would be easier for me to make different variables with each one its own condition and then order them as if they're one using created_at DESC.

```
@postActivity = PublicActivity::Activity.order("created_at DESC").where( owner_id: current_user.following.ids, key: 'posting' ).limit(20).all
@commentActivity = PublicActivity::Activity.order("created_at DESC").where( key: 'commenting' ).limit(20).all
```

The conditions are much more complicated than those above.
If you could point out a different way then sure do, appreciated.
PS. I'm a ruby newbie ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your specific samples, where conditions are multiplied (and), you can use ActiveRecord scopes - [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes)

They are made for the purpose of naming query conditions that you nicely combine in the code. Add scopes to your model, i.e. classes which inherit from  ActiveRecord::Base

```
class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :ordered, -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
  scope :commenting, -> { where(key: 'commenting') }
  scope :limit, -> { limit(20) }
..
```

And then to combine scopes (and condition) you just chanin

```
Activity.ordered.commenting.limit...
```

Meanwhile, there is a default_scope for something you include by default (e.g. order by)

For or condition (smt or smt) it's more complicated - you seems to use Arel.table (which is inside ActiveRecord) - see [here](https://www.viget.com/articles/composable-sql-queries-in-rails-using-arel) for example

Comment: But how can I combine both scopes? To order them

Comment: for and combination you just chain them -> ordered.commenting.etc.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, you should add scope calls to your ActiveRecord models. Pls check [docs link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes) - e.g. class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :published, -> { where(published: true) }
end

Answer (score 1):

ANDs and ORs work in controllers, did you mean in a query in your controller?  If you are trying to do a complex SQL query you can bypass active record to do the query in raw SQL.  Use rails find_by_sql method as shown here:  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#finding-by-sql